# Serialize Lucene StandardAnalyzer for Apache Spark RDD map transformation

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, lucene

I have a String SparkRDD (named RDD1) generated from a HDFS file. And I also have a list of String as dictionary. I want to apply a map function on RDD1 so that for each line of string, I do a search on top of a Lucene index built from the dictionary and return the top three match for each line. I'm using Lucene's TopScoreDocCollector to achieve this. I have no problems with the single machine version but once I run it on cluster it reports:

`ThrowableSerializationWrapper: Task exception could not be deserialized java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException`

My program logic is first create a broadcast variable from the dictionary(a string list). Then in the map function. I build a Lucene Index from that broadcast variable. I believe the error happens when I called:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

I believe this is not caused by forgot to add Lucene jars. I'm using the following program to run it.

```
spark-submit --class jinxuanw.clairvoyant.App --jars lucene-analyzers-common-5.3.1.jar,lucene-core-5.3.1.jar,lucene-queryparser-5.3.1.jar jobtitlematch-1.0.jar
```

Comment: In you custom jar check you are using same version of lucene-?-5.3.1.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `StandardAnalyzer` is not Serializable and hence cannot move such objects from the driver to the executor. Nevertheless, it is possible to instantiate such objects in the executors bypassing the serialisation issue.